# Expected response to contain an array but got an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, single-page-application

So I'm new in Angular, and I've looked over various other solutions, but no one seemed to work for me. My app needs to take some data from mongodb database and show it to the client. The thing is I get

> Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object

Here is my SchoolCtrl.js on the client

```
app.controller('SchoolsCtrl', function($scope, SchoolResource) {
    $scope.schools = SchoolResource.query();
});
```

Here is my ngResource

```
app.factory('SchoolResource', function($resource) {
    var SchoolResource = $resource('/api/schools/:id', {id: '@id'}, { update: {method: 'PUT', isArray: false}});
    return SchoolResource;
});
```

This is my SchoolsController on the server

```
var School = require('mongoose').model('School');

module.exports.getAllSchools = function(req, res, next) {
    School.find({}).exec(function(err, collection) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Schools could not be loaded: ' + err);
        }

        res.send(collection);
    })
};
```

I tried adding IsArray: true, tried adding [] after 'SchoolResource' in the resource, tried changing routes, nothing worked. I wanted to see what actually is returned, that the query complained is not array, so I turned it to string and this was the result:

> function Resource(value) { shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this); }

I have no idea why it returns a function. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Invoke the function (`function()`) to get your array.

Comment: Can you tell me which function? I tried the resource, tried the controller(though I don't know why would it work if I invoke the controller before it could get the data), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error message usually means your server is returning JSON representing a single object, such as:

```
{"some": "object", "with": "properties"}
```

when Angular is expecting JSON representing an array, like:

```
[ {"some": "object", "with": "properties"}, {"another": "object", "with": "stuff"} ]
```

Even if there is only a single result, `query` expects JSON for an array:

```
[ {"a": "single", "result": "object"} ]
```

You can verify this by simply loading your API call into the browser and checking it out. If there aren't square brackets around the whole JSON response, it isn't an array.

Comment: I figured, so I tried to see what is being returned by making it a string( there is probably a better way, but I didn't think of any), I thought it would be a JSON, but it actually was a function.

Comment: Just point your browser to `http://yourdomain.com/api/schools` and look at the JSON directly. That's what Angular is trying to parse.

Comment: As for printing, my guess is that you're trying to print `SchoolResource`. That is a constructor function (essentially a class). It won't print as anything useful. You won't be able to easily print out the object that is giving Angular trouble because it's not actually storing it anywhere useful -- Angular drops it like a hot potato once it realizes it's not an array. There are ways to intercept and inspect the value, but just viewing it in the browser is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, but then I printed the object in the console and found out that there was something like this:

```
{ options:{....},results:[ ...the Array I was looking for... ]}
```

so all you need to do there is

```
res.send(collection.results);
```

I hope this helps